# How to get distance between rectangle center and middle points

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have got rectangle bounds, used

```
map.getBounds();
```

Now I would like to calculate distance (in meters) between rectangle center and shorter middle point.

Already have some code:

```
var mapCenter = this.map.getCenter()
var mapBounds = this.map.getBounds();
var southEast = mapBounds.getSouthWest();
var middlePoint = ??;
var radius = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(mapCenter, middlePoint);
```

But I don't know how to get shorter distance (from center) middle point.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latitude of the "top" of the bounds is the northern latitude of the bounds: `mapBounds.getNorthEast().lat()`.  The longitude of the center of the bounds is the longitude of the center of the bounds `mapBounds.getCenter().lng()`

(if you don't know which side is the "shorter" one, calculate both and use the shorter value)

```
var mapCenter = map.getCenter()
var mapBounds = map.getBounds();
var southEast = mapBounds.getSouthWest();
var middlePoint = new google.maps.LatLng(mapBounds.getNorthEast().lat(), mapBounds.getCenter().lng());
var radius = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(mapCenter, middlePoint);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermyc1a9/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var mapCenter = map.getCenter()
    var mapBounds = map.getBounds();
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      map: map,
      bounds: mapBounds
    });
    var southEast = mapBounds.getSouthWest();
    var middlePoint = new google.maps.LatLng(mapBounds.getNorthEast().lat(), mapBounds.getCenter().lng());
    var radius = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(mapCenter, middlePoint);
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      center: mapCenter,
      radius: radius,
      map: map
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: middlePoint,
      map: map
    });
    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map,
      path: [mapCenter, middlePoint]
    });
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = radius.toFixed(2);
    map.setZoom(12);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```